# Имеет ли слово "новоявленный" негативный оттенок?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов, смысл

Чаще всего встречаю это слово в политическом контексте, например, когда не желают лишний раз называть имя или хотят создать легкий пренебрежительный окрас:

> ***новоявленный*** лидер профсоюзного движения.

Можно ли сказать:

> ***Новоявленный*** мастер спорта Андрей начал проводить тренировки в нашем клубе.

Несет ли тут (да и везде, кроме политики) слово "новоявленный" негативный смысл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Новоявленный мастер спорта Андрей начал проводить тренировки в нашем клубе.**

Думаю, что т**ак в нейтральном стиле писать нельзя**.

НОВОЯВЛЕННЫЙ,  Книжн. Недавно, только что возникший, появившийся, впервые проявивший себя. Н. супруг. Н. демократ. Н. пророк. Н-ая наука. Н-ое чудо света.

НОВОИСПЕЧЁННЫЙ,  **Шутл.** Только что, недавно сделанный, созданный или ставший кем-л. Н. проект. Н-ые курсанты. Н. врач. Н. профессор.

Хотя ***новоявленный*** помечено  в словаре  только как книжн., но мне кажется, что **у слова явно иронический оттенок.**

Из книги Русский язык. Культура речи. Учебное пособие.

Например, слова *новоявленный, новоиспеченный* имеют **ироническую окраску**. http://window.edu.ru/catalog/pdf2txt/005/41005/18310?p_page=11